# Convert SQLite/FMDB NSArray format

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsstring, nsarray, fmdb

Question about SQLite and FMDB, I'm going to save NSArray *insertParams into SQLite, the format of insertParams is like below:

> (
>           {
>           action = "\U8d5e\U540c\U4e86\U8be5\U56de\U7b54";
>           content = "\U8c22zolo\U9080\Uff0c\U65b0\U5e74\U5feb\U4e50~\U81ea\U5df1\U548c\U5bb6\U4eba\U8eab\U4f53\U5b89\U5eb7\U3002";
>           "post_id" = 114834;
>           "post_type" = "a";
>           score = 1;
>           title = "\U5927\U5bb6\U6765\U4e3a2013\U5e74\U7684\U65b0\U5e74\U8bb8\U613f\U5427\Uff1f\U4f60\U7684\U613f\U671b\U662f\U4ec0\U4e48\Uff1f";
>           user =         {
>               "avatar_url" = "/statics/images/thumb_d04a6fc94214e61a0f35f70b50387b18.jpg";
>               id = 7151;
>               name = abc;
>               nickname = abc;
>           };
>       },
>           {
>           action
>           ................
>           ................
>           ................

The data was perfactly saved, however, when I retrive the data from SQLite, because there is no such arrayForColumn function, so I have to use stringForColumn function to get data as below:

> NSString *content = [results stringForColumn:@"content"];
>
> [resultArray addObject:content];

However the format of the resultArray has been changed to below:

> (
>           "{\n    action = \"\U8d5e\U540c\U4e86\U8be5\U56de\U7b54\";\n    content =
>   \"\U8c22zolo\U9080\Uff0c\U65b0\U5e74\U5feb\U4e50~\U81ea\U5df1\U548c\U5bb6\U4eba\U8eab\U4f53\U5b89\U5eb7\U3002\";\n
>   \"post_id\" = 114834;\n    \"post_type\" = \"a\";\n    score = 1;\n
>   title =
>   \"\U5927\U5bb6\U6765\U4e3a2013\U5e74\U7684\U65b0\U5e74\U8bb8\U613f\U5427\Uff1f\U4f60\U7684\U613f\U671b\U662f\U4ec0\U4e48\Uff1f\";\n
>   user =     {\n        \"avatar_url\" =
>   \"/statics/images/thumb_d04a6fc94214e61a0f35f70b50387b18.jpg\";\n
>   id = 7151;\n        name = abc;\n        nickname = abc;\n    };\n}",
>           "{\n    action
>           ................
>           ................
>           ................

Could any one tell me that how to format the result as the original NSArray *insertParams's format?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over thinking the problem a bit.  FMDB (and consequently, SQL) is quite good about handling NSData instances, so you can simply use `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` to convert to and from the NSData object to your array.  Retrieving it is a matter of calling `-dataForColumn` after executing your query.